# Why my javascript variable becomes an array in PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I've used ajax to pass my javascript variable "**speechResult**" to PHP file "**readJson.php**" successfully with a little bit of *error!*

Why my javascript variable **becomes an array in PHP**?!

Let's have a look at my javascript first :

```
var speechResult= "reza"; 

$.ajax({
    url:"readJson.php",
    method: "post",
    data: speechResult,
    success: function(res) {
             console.log(res)
    }
  });
```

then my readJson.php code here :

```
<?php
    print($_POST);
?>
```

and finally here is my console log :

> Array

if I use this I'll get reza again ...

```
<?php
    print_r($_POST);
?>
```

here is my console log :

> Array (
>       [reza] =>  )

Comment: PHP provides the individual parameters send with a GET or POST request in the superglobal _arrays_ $_GET/ $_POST … that is simply how it works.

Comment: Arrays can not be output in text form using echo or print, that will always only get you the text “Array” as result. You can use print_r or var_dump to see what your array contains; if you want to output a specific (text) element of that array via echo/post, then you have to access it specifically: `echo $_POST['reza'];`

Comment: Sorry guys, it's my first day in PHP please go easy on me How Can I define $phpVar with speechResult?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By accessing $_POST you are asking for the key-value pair representation of the data that was sent to the server. And as you did not send key-value pairs, that does not really make any sense.

If you want the raw post data, use `file_get_contents("php://input");` instead:

```
<?php
    $data = file_get_contents("php://input");
    print($data);
```

The alternative would be to send key-value pairs from javascript:

```
data: {'speechResult': speechResult},
```

Now you will have your data in `$_POST['speechResult']`

Comment: Thank you Jeroen, I'll test this and come back to you... But just a question should I put data: {'speechResult': speechResult}, in my javascript code and print($_POST['speechResult']) in my php file ?

Comment: @SaraRee Exactly, but make sure you replace the `data` line you already have in your javascript.

Comment: That Works Like a Charm Sir :) please accept my best regards.